# Morphisms from projective space to lower dimension spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a variety over a base field $k$ of dimension $n$. Can there be non constant morphisms $P^m \to X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is answered negatively [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/116398) (assuming $m>n$).

Comment: That's great, thank you! Google did not turn up that thread at all :(