# When are there no maps from a variety of high dimension to a variety of low dimension?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

It's easy to show that the only maps from $\mathbb P^{n+d} \to \mathbb P^n$ are the constant maps for $d \geq 1$. Given two smooth, projective varieties $X,Y$ of dimensions $n+d,n$ as above, are there any nice, general conditions under which the only maps between them are constant? It's not always true as the example $X = Z\times Y \to Y$ shows.

By Noether normalization, we can assume that $Y = \mathbb P^n$ so I believe we are looking for conditions on $X$ so that any $n+1$ divisors on $X$ intersect non trivially.

Comment: Why do you suspect the conditions on intersection of n+1 divisors?

Comment: @EvansGambit I had in my mind the proof in OP in your linked post but I might have mixed up trivially with non trivially and n with n+1.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is a [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116398/schemes-with-no-nonconstant-maps-to-lower-dimensional-schemes) on families of examples where such a property holds.

Comment: Aha, it seems like my question is pretty much a duplicate. Let me close my question then and thank you for the link!